# Convert specific time format to in PHP to MYSQL datetime type

Tags: php

I need some help about time formatting.

The input I get from a file is (for example): Wed Jun 28 19:12:55 CEST 2015, so: name of the day  Month(text) Day  Hour:minute:second  Timezone Year.

I would like to convert it to Mysql datetime format, to be able to store in a database.

The format is (for example): 2016-03-06 12:09:44, which is Year-Month (number)-Day Hour-Minute-Second

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use date function of php.

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($yourDateTimeVariable));
```

for more help see php manual for date.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope it helps

Comment: It works, thank you! I thought it will be more complicated.